# synchronize fails with rsync_opts

Tags: ansible

Running ansible command with `synchronize` module and `rsync_opts` fails with error:

```
$ ansible all -i testvm, -m synchronize -a "src=./ dest=/etc/audit/rules.d mode=push owner=no group=no recursive=no rsync_opts=--chown=root:root" -b
testvm | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "cmd": "/usr/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --no-recursive --no-owner --no-group --rsh='/usr/bin/ssh -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null' --rsync-path='sudo -u root rsync' --chown=root:root --out-format='<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L' /Users/xxxxxxxx/auditd/rules.d/ testvm:/etc/audit/rules.d",
    "msg": "rsync: --chown=root:root: unknown option\nrsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/main.c(1337) [client=2.6.9]\n",
    "rc": 1
}
```

I tried with different quotation marks/escapes without success.

The command itself works fine when I remove `rsync_opts=--chown=root:root`

I need to synchronise folder with ansible+become from local user to target system changing owner of the files in final location to root:root. There is no direct access too root account via ssh so I can't run rsync directly.

The copy module is too slow.

Answer (score 2):

The error you received is very clear:

```
rsync: --chown=root:root: unknown option
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at /AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync/main.c(1337) [client=2.6.9]
```

The error implies that the version of rsync you're running is older than 3.1.0, when the `--chown` option was introduced. This is backed up by the version reported later in the output, `[client=2.6.9]`.

In order to use this functionality you need to upgrade to a version of rsync that supports it.